# Should my html markup be generated on the client side?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, performance

I have some server side code that outputs a `<ul>` of items that the user can edit and post changes back to the server.  I am now working on an "Add New" feature that adds a new item to the `<ul>` and will be posted back to the server when the 'save changes' button is clicked.

When the user clicks the "Add New" button, I execute client side code that appends `<li>` markup *(same markup generated by my server side code)*.

What is bugging me is the redundancy.  Meaning that if I should change the `<li>` markup, I would have to open both php and js files to do the change.

In the interest of eliminating redundancy, should I only output the `<ul>` **data** from the server and let the client code generate the markup?  What are the performance hits from a concept like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a hybrid using the JQuery `.clone()` method.

Your back-end code could produce the structure of the `<li>` elements when it is creating the initial code and then, if the user wanted to add a new `<li>`, you could grab on of the existing ones to use as a template, `.clone()` it, update the values of the clone with the new data from the user, then append it to the `<ul>`.

The only issue would be if there was a possibility that there might not be any `<li>` elements on page load, so the `.clone()` call would have nothing to reference.  There are ways around that if it's an issue though (e.g., a JS `string` template of the `<li>` format that you want to use, that could be used like this:  `var newLI = $(liTemplateString);`.  Again, this template could be created by the same code on the back-end that would create the actual `<li>` elements on page load . . . it would just be creating a JS variable as well.

Amongst other things, this would allow you to update the `<li>` to the page immediately and then send the update to the back-end using Ajax, to update the "master" version, without making the user wait on that process.

In the end, my personal preference is to let the back-end do as much of the processing as possible and only you client-side code to handle the things that the back-end can't do, so I would shy away from dumping data and letting the front-end handle building the list, if the back-end can do it as it's creating the page.

Comment: I love this answer! You bring up an important point about a possible empty list.  A template string would be perfect for this scenario. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can just append the new `<li>` with no problems. However, for most uses, you will want the server to hold the master copy, thus re-serving the entire `<ul>` for each update.

If you're using `.ajax()`, this will be a nearly immeasurable difference in load time.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest the Third Way: duplicate an existing element and change its properties and/or content as needed.

jQuery has `.clone()`, but it can be done with plain DOM or any other library as well.

This way you don't add unneeded latency and you keep your client-side code *relatively* independent of any markup changes you might have to do. Meaning that if you add or change any markup that's unrelated to what the JS needs to do (for example adding a `class=""` or an inner `<span>`) and your JS is sufficiently generic (for example getting the element to clone and the one whose text to edit from attributes) then you don't need to update it.